# Card view not working below Lollipop version

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I am using card view but the elevation and card view properties are not working below version 5.0.

I tried to use card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" by searching some SO posts but this also did not work.

It should look like this

[image]

And it looks like this on 4.2.2

[image]

Here is layout:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="05dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="12dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/bg">

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/cardLineColor"></View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_id"
                android:layout_width="103dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ID"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                android:text="23/3/2015"
                android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:textSize="10sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_trans_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="sent money"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_trans_type"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_trans_type"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_balance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="$3214"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                android:text="@string/balance"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Edit: I created 9 patch file like this

[image]

But this is giving this error:

```
Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
```

May be its height width is much? I tried with small height width but then it leaves some gap. How can I match it to all devices?

Comment: Hard to tell whether the elevation is working or not with this background color - at least I can't see a difference. Nevertheless the `cardElevation` property should also work for pre-lollipop devices. Other than that: You should define the `backgroundColor` not in the `RelativeLayout` but in the `CardView` directly via `cardBackgroundColor`.

Comment: I tried to define background via     app:cardBackgroundColor ="@color/bg" , it still shows white. @reVerse

Comment: I just tested it with your layout and my recommendations and I got a drop shadow and no white surroundings on my API-Level 19 emulator - so everything seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, elevation, as you mentioned it, is not available for API 19 and below.

The solution I chose for my similar issue is to replace my cardviews by regular layouts and use 9-patch images as background to generate the shadows. It has the advantage to be very modulable, plus, unlike the elevation property, you can have more customization like shadow colors if you don't want a simple black shadow.

The only problem is that you have to design the image yourself and add it to the project. But fear not, there is some handy generators like [this one](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/) that can generate it for you. Just make sure that you set a minimum size that is less than your layout to be sure it fits without deforming it. I usually generates a 10*10 pixels wide image, and shadows won't be deformed even when applied to a much larger view.

When you got your image (name should look like myimage.9.png), you simply add it to your drawables, without removing the .9.png extension, and then set it as a regular background drawable to your layout, via xml or code. And you're done !

EDIT : Did not notice you also have lighting on the top of the cardview.. What you can try if you have something like Photoshop, is to create yourself the 9-patch, by applying drop shadows for the dark one, then creating a second layer to add another drop shadow but this time set to white and with the appropriate angle to display it above. Then you save it as png and use the 9-patch generator to convert it to a .9.png image.

[See the 9-patch documentation here.](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/help/draw9patch.html) If you're using Android Studio, there is also a built-in generator for 9-patches.

Sadly, user interface was kinda limited for advanced displaying like shadows before Material Design stepped in with Android 5. Maybe you can add your cardviews programmatically, so you can do something like this

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    //Add regular layout to your views with 9 patch
} else{
    //Add cardview to get desired effect
}
```

That way most of your users will have your desired cardviews, but it can quickly increase the amount of code you'll need if you need your element to be clickable/draggable/etc.

Comment: I tried but I could not make the same image background . dose not look good. :-(

Comment: See the edited answer. Will be hard to get such advanced look to your views for pre-lollipop devices though..

Comment: Mmmh, strange. Crunch fail can happen for two main reasons : if you're on Windows and the path to the file is extremely long, Windows path limitations can prevent a proper loading when compiling. If your absolute file path is long, try copying your project to a shorter path and see what happens. The other thing is that you renamed your image.png to image.9.png without using a 9 patch tool. The trick here is to use Android Studio or the draw9patch app located in your SDK path/tools to open it, save it and it should work.

Comment: I saved image from the website u gave and used the same image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:cardElevation="12dp"`
instead of `card_view:cardElevation="12dp"`
Hope it helps.

Comment: try removing app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"